# Grails domain class cannot have a property named 'target'?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a class with a property named 'target' that was being used in Grails 1.3.9.  We are currently upgrading to 2.5.1.

For some reason (call my class 'MyClass'), when I call (an instance 'myClass') myClass.target, it thinks I want the unwrapped proxy object for 'myClass' and returns that (that's how it appears in the debugger, at least -- examining myClass gives an object with a different address and all-null properties, whereas myClass.target gives all the fully-realized property values).  To get to my actual property, I have to use myClass.target.target.

I can't find anything documented about 'target' being a reserved word, or a special method, or what have you -- searching hasn't found more.

I tried this on a different class (with no target property) using .load to get a proxy, and .target returned the unwrapped proxy for it as well.  So somewhere along the line this must have gotten added.

Does anyone have information about this method/property?  I can try renaming my property, but it's used all over the place, so I just want to understand what I'm up against here.

Comment: This may be an aid for others, but I suspect that the "target" property is used by Grails to convert model objects into other formats (Collections, JSON, etc.)  I say that because I have had the word "target" appear in my JsonOutput.toJson where I've been manipulating model data (in 2.4.5)